# Extending Theme Options to Child Themes in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I have purchased the Honest theme. I have also created a child theme for some look/feel changes. In my child theme I have also created an additional custom post-type.

For some reason the Honest theme options are not available in my child theme dashboard. Since I have a custom post-type I don't want to simply use the parent theme because any updates will overwrite my custom post-type.

Is there a way to make the parent theme options available in a child theme? If so, can you point me toward a direction of that solution?

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say without seeing the actual source code.

If you're willing to use the parent theme, you can put the code that registers the custom post type in a plugin of your own. Must-use plugins are great for this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins

You can also put your style mods there, e.g. enqueue an extra stylesheet that overrides the styles from the parent theme: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style